# remove parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with the fields inside table cells.   On the last column of each line I have an image. When clicking that image I want to delete the parent `<tr>`. Before I tried to do it by generating a function passing as the argument the line number: `onclick='delete_row(x, y)'`. This is obviously not a good solution since I was deleting the row by its position. The function I'm calling has other 2 arguments since it deletes the row in the database too, so the second argument is the id in the database to delete. So basically I need a function that deletes the parent `<tr>` and that accept some other arguments too.

EDIT Thanks:
Thank you all guys, I tried almost all the solutions and all worked nice. I just decided for the Mike's Samuel one, it seemed the easiest :) Thanks again

Comment: you should always include code you have tried so farp in your questions

Comment: Sorry Michal, I didn't include any code since I didn't have one :) I just didn't know how to do it :) Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the grandparent of the current node use `this.parentNode.parentNode`:

```
<tr><td><img onclick="delete_row(this.parentNode.parentNode, ...)"></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the closest `<tr>`? You would need to make accommodations for the selectors that are present in *your* code, but the general form looks like this:

```
$('img').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use the HTML node method [`.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) and traverse through the node's [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode)s: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUKDP/)):

```
<td onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">
    Remove row
</td>
```

`this.parentNode.parentNode` will be the `<table>` or `<tbody>`, while `this.parentNode` is the parent container `<tr>`.

---

**Update**: [rjz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040371/rjz) provided a neat function ([demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/B7vqt/2/)):

```
window.removeClosestRow = function(node) {
    while(node = node.parentNode) {
        if (node.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'TR') {
           node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
           break;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: This would work if the event handler were on the table cell, but the event handler is on an image inside the cell.

Comment: The thought still works, I think, but you would want to recurse up until `parentNode.tagName=='TR'` instead of just copy-pasting `parentNode.` :^)

Comment: Mike: Well, he could easily use `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`, although that's a little bit harder to read. rjz: Yeah, I was working on a fiddle, but I'm currently in a hurry so I won't be able to finish it :/.

Answer (score -1):

try something like

```
onClick='MyDeleteFunc(this, var2, var3)';
```

that will pass the actual object you're clicking on to javascript, and you can get pretty much all your references from there.

Comment: ... I don't mind getting voted down, but why?  This is perfectly valid stuff.